# Why are $\sigma$-algebras defined to be closed under countable-fold set operations?

Tags: measure-theory, discrete-mathematics

I recently started to learn measure theory and one of the beginning points was that a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ that is closed under countable-fold set operations. I was wondering why $\sigma$-algebra's were chosen to have those two exact conditions and not more, such as being closed under multiplication? In general, I was also wondering why certain mathematical objects were defined to have the attributes they have, like the "memoryless" property of Markov Chains. My understanding has always been that certain mathematical objects are defined with properties because of the nice properties or nice proofs that follow. Once we get data to conform to any pre-supposed conditions, we have nice analytical-form solutions that follow. Is this line of thinking correct?, Thanks!

Comment: What would it mean for a $\sigma$-algebra to be closed under multiplication?  What kind of multiplication do you have in mind?

Comment: We don't make definitions because they lead to nice proofs, that would be putting the cart before the horse.  We make definitions for more properly motivated reasons.  For example, around 1900 we had a rigorous theory of integration over intervals.  But because of things like probability theory people began to see the need to extend it to more general sets of real numbers.  They soon found out they could not properly extend the concept to any subset.  This lead very naturally to the definition of $\sigma$-algebra.  The need drove the definition, not the other way around.